# How to use UISegmentedControl with UITableView and Segmented Control and SearchBar NOT scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on iPad App. I want to implement hidden Segment (Files, Folder,All) under Search Bar. When SearchBar is get focused then Segment Control will take place under SearchBar. Make sure SearchBar and Segment Controller didn't Scroll.

[image]

Anyone give me Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a view controller and open .xib file and place search bar and segmented control in your UIView and out of UITableView. Connect all IBOutlets and delegates. You may get focus in this method `- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

in this method you will show your segmented control. Before this step you will have to hide your segmented control in `viewDidLoad`.
In the following method you may hide your segmented control again

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Method for cancel button is:

```
 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

for search button method is:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Now this is up to you how do you want to use these methods. In this way none of your search bar or tabbar will scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Add UISearchBar object and UISegmentControll object to tableView's header view.

Comment: check the below link it's a good one.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view